# prove that there is no supremum for mn/1+m+n

Tags: calculus

D = { mn/(1+m+n) } for m,n natural numbers.

To simplify the expression, I presumed m=n, which means:
D = { n^2 / (2n + 1) }

Now, I know by intuition **there is no supremum**, for this series convergencing to infinity, but I couldn't find a formal way to prove it.

I thought about proving by contradiction:
- assume S is the supremum
- ϵ > 0
S - ϵ > n^2 / (2n + 1)

But then I got stuck..

Any guideness will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please use parentheses.  $mn/1+m+n=mn+m+n$ which I am sure is not what you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: we can set $n = k$, $m = k-1$ to get 
$$
\frac{mn}{1+m+n}=
\frac{k(k-1)}{1 + k + k-1} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2k} = \frac{k-1}{2}
$$
Thus, $\frac{k-1}{2}\in D$ for every $k\geq 2$.
So, if $D$ has a supremum, then the supremum of $D$ is bigger than $\frac{k-1}{2}$ for every integer $k$.  Why does this result in a contradiction?

Comment: Why is it a contradiction? Couldn't figure it out..

Comment: Start with an $S$.  Can you find a $k$ so that $\frac{k+1}{2}>S$?

Comment: mmm.. k > 2S - 1?

Comment: Right. And by the Archimedean property of the integers (that is, because the integers have no upper bound), we can always choose such a $k$.  Since we can always find a $\frac{k+1}{2}$ bigger than any choice of $S$, no choice of $S$ could possibly be bigger than every element in $D$.  That is, no $S$ qualifies as an upper bound of $D$.

Comment: many thanks my friend

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $mn = k(k-1)$  then $\frac{k-1}{2}$

Comment: @Wmmoreno thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try rewriting the fraction by doing division. If you are working in the reals, the least-upper-bound property tells you that any set with an upper bound has a supremum, so if you want to show the set has no supremum, you should be showing it has no upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{n^2}{2n+1} \ge \frac{n^2}{3n} =n/3$$

Comment: a) So, you're suggesting just showing n/3 has no supremum?

Comment: Why can you this by the way? (Changing the expression like that)